# ArcGIS Online Deep Leaning Error:999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, classification, error-999999, deep-learning

Have you ever faced this error while using ArcGIS Online Deep Learning tool and trying to analyze Tiled Imagery layer?

> ClassifyPixelsUsingDeepLearning failed. Start Time: Sunday, December
> 18, 2022 1:28:03 PM ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool
> to fail.Contact Esri Technical Support (esriurl.com/support) to Report
> a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or
> workarounds. Unable to prepare input raster(s) for the python raster
> function. Unable to open the specified raster. [raster] Unable to
> extract and reorder raster bands.Invalid band index encountered.
> [requested band 4 at position 4] Unable to prepare input raster(s) for
> the python raster function. Unable to open the specified raster.
> [raster] Unable to extract and reorder raster bands. Invalid band
> index encountered. [requested band 4 at position 4] Unable to prepare
> input raster(s) for the python raster function. Unable to open the
> specified raster. [raster] Unable to extract and reorder raster bands.
> Invalid band index encountered. [requested band 4 at position 4]
> Failed to execute (ClassifyPixelsUsingDeepLearning). Failed at Sunday,
> December 18, 2022 1:29:53 PM (Elapsed Time: 1 minutes 49 seconds).

Comment: I am trying to analyse Landsat 8 imagery ( i don't know if it's important or not)

Comment: Yes, a description of what you are trying to do is important. So important, in fact, that it belongs at the top of the Question.